# How does getCurrentTime work under GHCJS?

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

Under GHCJS, how does `getCurrentTime` work? In the `time` library itself, this is [implemented using the FFI](https://github.com/haskell/time/blob/1b74336b646b6bd3e36eee3efa00f41b915f02c7/lib/Data/Time/Clock/CTimespec.hsc), calling out to functions provided by the operating system. However, there aren't any lines in `time` that start with:

```
foreign import javascript ...
```

I've checked the `shims` repository that GHCJS using to patch libraries. It [patches the timezone getting function](https://github.com/ghcjs/shims/blob/570494fe9ff9278ec1e5df01c450bd19e7d0adcc/pkg/time.js) but has no mention of `getCurrentTime`. The only thing I found that was remotely close was in `ghcjs-boot`, where `old-time` is patched with an:

```
#ifdef ghcjs_HOST_OS
type CTimeVal = ()
type CTimeZone = ()
...
foreign import ccall unsafe "HsTime.h __hscore_gettimeofday"
    gettimeofday :: Ptr CTimeVal -> Ptr CTimeZone -> IO CInt
...
```

But there are two problems with this. One is that it's not the right library (`old-time` instead of `time`). The other is that it's still using the C FFI. I don't understand how the using the C FFI can work when you are compiling with GHCJS.

So, where does `getCurrentTime` get shimmed in for GHCJS?

In response to the comment about grepping ghcjs source, if I search for `getTime` (which I believe would be the javascript function used) in GHCJS's source, I get basically nothing. However, by grepping an `all.js` file produced by GHCJS for a project that uses `getCurrentTime`, I get this:

```
ag '\bgetTime\b' all.js
20948:  h$log((("elapsed time: " + (h$RTS_597.getTime() - h$RTS_595.getTime())) + "ms"));
22863:                var atime = goog.math.Long.fromNumber(fs.atime.getTime());
22864:                var mtime = goog.math.Long.fromNumber(fs.mtime.getTime());
22865:                var ctime = goog.math.Long.fromNumber(fs.ctime.getTime());
```

The latter three are from some kind of filesystem shim.

I found this in the generated javascript:

```
function h$gettimeofday(tv_v,tv_o,tz_v,tz_o) {
  var now = Date.now();
  tv_v.dv.setInt32(tv_o, (now / 1000)|0, true);
  tv_v.dv.setInt32(tv_o + 4, ((now % 1000) * 1000)|0, true);
  if(tv_v.len >= tv_o + 12) {
    tv_v.dv.setInt32(tv_o + 8, ((now % 1000) * 1000)|0, true);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But the question of how this got linked in remains.

Comment: Could you `grep -r` the GHCJS source searching for the JS time primitive?

Comment: @dfeuer I've added the results. I think that it might not be `getTime` that gets used by GHCJS. Although that seems that the obvious choice for POSIX time.

Comment: Ah, it's actually `Date.now`. I'll add the source I found.

Comment: It looks more like a primitive than something "linked in", so you might check the code generator. That `h$` could even be a special pattern it looks for. I could be wrong though!

Comment: I discovered `h$gettimeofday` in shims `src/environment.js` https://github.com/ghcjs/shims/blob/master/src/environment.js#L243